# How to use LUA script in Python or TensorFlow?

Tags: python, deep-learning, lua, wrapper, tensorflow2.0

I am experimenting with few deep learning models for my project and one of the models I downloaded from GitHub was written in LUA programming language. I have no prior experience with LUA. Is it possible to run the LUA script in Python or TensorFlow?

Thank you.

Comment: Check [these](https://wiki.python.org/moin/IntegratingPythonWithOtherLanguages#Lua) packages out for integrating python and lua